# ld: 600 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, linker, duplicate-symbol

```
/Users/iph8/Documents/Avi/Current project/XYZ/SourceCode/April12/XYZ_April_12/XYZ/Frameworks/AppLovin/libAppLovinSdk.a(ALTaskCacheNativeAdImages.o)

ld: 600 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Getting this error while running the project on simulator and not able to detect why it's happening while the same code runs on other computers, but not on my computer.

Comment: may be u have used some name more than once in your project

Comment: there are more than 200 files, how to check all files?

Comment: it was not running because of version problem.

Comment: are you able to explain the version fix?

Answer (score 1):

This may happen in the following cases.

- You have put the same class implementation into two different files;
- You actually have just one implementation of this class, however you are also linking in your project a framework or library containing a class whose name is exactly the same of yours.

Try finding in the whole project your class and make sure only one copy is available within your project.

Comment: actually in my project there are 198 files and it is not easily possible to check each and every file.

Comment: Are you importing the library twice? Or the dependencies? Check it.

Comment: i have checked all the libraires are added only once.

Comment: thank you patrick for your help... actually yesterday i got the solution is that code was not running because of xcode version problem, my xcode version is 6.4 and it was running on xcode 7 or above.